# Webdriver Watir Ruby Chrome Versions

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to test with different versions of Chrome. How can you point at a specific Chrome executable/version with Watir and Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a specific Chrome executable specify the `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path`.

```
require 'watir'

# Note that the path includes the file directory and executable
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/Chrome.exe'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Comment: Works great but you need to require selenium-webdriver as well. Once the answer is corrected I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: You only need to `require 'selenium-webdriver'` if you are using an older version of Watir. As of Watir 6.0, it is just Watir-Webdriver, not the metagem for selecting between Watir-Classic and Watir-Webdriver. As a result, `require 'watir'` [already does the necessary `require 'selenium-webdriver'`](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/lib/watir.rb#L1).

Comment: Sorry...had an old reference that brought in the old version of watir. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hi Justin Ko, I don't understand the meaning of metagem, this name is given because it chooses between two gems ?

Comment: @Gopal, that is correct. Watir v5 (and maybe 3/4), was simply a gem that loaded Watir-Classic or Watir-Webdriver based on the browser selected. Basically if you wanted to test IE, it loaded Watir-Classic, otherwise it would load Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: Okay, thank you but why did you use the word 'meta'?